# Generate POSTMAN in webpage with JSON or something

Tags: json, jsonp, postman

I have a restAPI code from a programmer from JNE, company stands for delivery service.

They say that this API can be run in POSTMAN (Google Chrome Application)

It works fine in the POSTMAN, where in this application I just need to insert the `request URL` (which I have got from the JNE company) and two header of keys and values as follow;

```
 KEY                          VALUE
----------------------------------------------
username                      mycompany
api key                       4534645756864234523424
```

The method for this is `POST` and when I posted it, it gives me the results as how expected.

My problem now is, how can I run this code in my page, so that I don't need to run this in postman.

I am just this day going to learn JSON if anybody can help me out with this.

**[UPDATE QUESTION 1]**

```
{
"version":1,
"collections":
    [
        {
            "id":"c8b12431-8586-cbdd-aef7-056ec177509a",
            "name":"asdasdadasdasdasd",
            "timestamp":1415593872130,
            "requests":
                [
                    {
                        "collectionId":"c8b12431-8586-cbdd-aef7-056ec177509a",

                        "id":"d1b2ed66-781d-d02e-c4eb-0416dd3e07a1",

                        "name":"http://api.jne.co.id:8889/tracing/mycompany/origin/key/jak",

                        "description":"",

                        "url":"http://api.jne.co.id:8889/tracing/mycompany/origin/key/jak",

                        "method":"POST",

                        "headers":"username: mycompany\napi_key:089a12ffb8cd5009bdfa4ba5bdb9ee26\n",

                        "data":
                                [   
                                    {
                                        "key":"username",
                                        "value":"mycompany",
                                        "type":"text"
                                    },

                                    {
                                        "key":"api_key",
                                         "value":"dsfsdfsdfs98d98sdfsdf9898dsfs",
                                         "type":"text"
                                    }
                                ],

                        "dataMode":"params",
                        "timestamp":0,
                        "responses":[],
                        "version":2
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],



"environments":[],
"headerPresets":[],
"globals":[]
}
```

From the update question above; my first question is: ]

In what format I have to save this file: JSON? or WHAT?

Should I save this file in one file with my webpage? or Can I save it as external file?

From the code above, I get the result as follow:

```
  {
            "detail": [
                {
                    "code": "CGK10000",
                    "label": "JAKARTA"
                },
                {
                    "code": "CGK10100",
                    "label": "JAKARTA BARAT"
                },
                {
                    "code": "CGK10300",
                    "label": "JAKARTA PUSAT"
                },
                {
                    "code": "CGK10200",
                    "label": "JAKARTA SELATAN"
                },
                {
                    "code": "CGK10500",
                    "label": "JAKARTA TIMUR"
                },
                {
                    "code": "CGK10400",
                    "label": "JAKARTA UTARA"
                }
            ]
        }
```

---

If you have a look to the `"label"` it is generated from the key of the last string in the: `"name":"http://api.jne.co.id:8889/tracing/mycompany/origin/key/jak",`

---

---

The result of the label from the last string of `jak`, is what I want to insert in a dropdown html tag, in where the user will choose that (the name of the location).

---

---

---

**[Update with complete code]**

```
 POST /tracing/mycompany/origin/key/jak HTTP/1.1
 Host: api.jne.co.id:8889

 Content-Type: application/json  
 username: mycompany
 api_key: 089a12ffb8cd5009bdfa4ba5bdb9ee26

{
"version":1,
"collections":
    [
        {
            "id":"c8b12431-8586-cbdd-aef7-056ec177509a",
            "name":"asdasdadasdasdasd",
            "timestamp":1415593872130,
            "requests":
                [
                    {
                        "collectionId":"c8b12431-8586-cbdd-aef7-056ec177509a",

                        "id":"d1b2ed66-781d-d02e-c4eb-0416dd3e07a1",

                        "name":"http://api.jne.co.id:8889/tracing/mycompany/origin/key/jakarta",

                        "description":"",

                        "url":"http://api.jne.co.id:8889/tracing/mycompany/origin/key/jakarta",

                        "method":"POST",

                        "headers":"username: mycompany\napi_key:089a12ffb8cd5009bdfa4ba5bdb9ee26\n",

                        "data":
                                [   
                                    {
                                        "key":"username",
                                        "value":"mycompany",
                                        "type":"text"
                                    },

                                    {
                                        "key":"api_key",
                                         "value":"089a12ffb8cd5009bdfa4ba5bdb9ee26",
                                         "type":"text"
                                    }
                                ],

                        "dataMode":"params",
                        "timestamp":0,
                        "responses":[],
                        "version":2
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],



"environments":[],
"headerPresets":[],
"globals":[]
}
```

---

---

---

I have saved this file as `jne.json` and `jne.html` but the browser just show the full code insted show the result as how the postman does. I think there are many things I am missing here.

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: I am sorry sir, as far as I have this time, I am using PHP in my webpage. But I think this restAPI is using JSON. I will learn it if have to, because this is the first time I face JSON. Help

Comment: This is not focused on JSON, it is more about HTTP. JSON is only used for the payload. You could also use XML. JSON itself is really simple. You will find a lot of information on [this site](http://www.json.org). To get the same results as in Postman you have to construct the same request in PHP (which I'm not that familiar with), which means you need to post your JSON payload to the given URL and add the two headers to the request.

Comment: If you only can help me in specific programming language, that's alright. I just need to have an idea on how to run this restApi in programming language.

Comment: That's what I wrote above. Create a new HTTP Post request. The request URL is the one given to you. To this request you add the two headers (username and api key) with their values. You also need to set the Content-Type header to application/json (Postman does that automatically for you). As the last step you add the JSON payload to the body of the request. These are the steps in every programming language thanks to HTTP.

Comment: Please have a look at my update question. There I got some code from the postman with the key and value I just inserted. Now my first question is in what format i have to save this file? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The POST request would look something like the following

```
POST /tracing/mycompany/origin/key/jak HTTP/1.1
Host: api.jne.co.id:8889

Content-Type: application/json
username: mycompany
api_key: 089a12ffb8cd5009bdfa4ba5bdb9ee26

{
    ... your JSON ...
}
```

You can save JSON with the *.json* file extension. If your request is always the same you can save this file with your webpage, but normally an HTTP request is constructed before sending (that means you normally send different requests).
To fill the dropdown list you just have to parse the JSON response.

Comment: is what you tagged as `... your JSON ...` is the code I have written above? thanks

Comment: Yes, except the header fields you added afterwards. They belong to the HTTP header.

Comment: You are missing that you have to make an HTTP Post request. A browser normally does a Get request. That is one reason for tools like Postman.

Comment: tell me how to do that?

Comment: Either you use a tool such as Postman or Curl or a programming language. For the programming language you should visit the appropriate documentation.

Comment: @Horizon_Net, Why is there a new line between the headers? Wouldn't that break the header parsing?

Comment: @Pacerier What new line? The first two line are host information, then three lines of header information and after that comes the body. You can delete the lines between. They are just for better readability. Also the original question was about Postman where you don't pass the blank request in. You specifiy the HTTP method and the host, then your headers and a body if you like.